# How to use ViteJS generated assets in Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, vite

I'm currently making web app with spring as an backend and react as an frontend. I'm using ViteJS for building my assets, and when they are built, they have some kind of hash attached to end (index-e906df4e.js for example). I found out I can also generate manifest.json file that have mapping of my original file names and their build ones so I figured out I can use that. My question is there any better way for doing this in Spring then manually parsing manifest.json and passing it to thymeleaf via model attributes.